# EC2 Socket Connection

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, redis, socket.io, socket.io-redis

I tried to use socket.io with EC2 and laravel.

Here's my code in server side - server.js

```
var app = require('express')();
var server = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(server);
var redis = require('redis');

console.log("hello");

server.listen(8890, function(){
    console.log("8890");
});

io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
    console.log("connected");
});
```

When I test in localhost, everything is fine. I can connect and emit.

When I `node server.js` in localhost, the result will be like this.

```
hello
8890
connected
```

But when I `node server.js` in EC2 instance, the result will be like this. Seems like it cannot connect the socket.io.

```
hello
8890
```

I have already install redis, node, npm and express in the EC2 instance and tested they are running.

I had also set the security group of my instance for port 8890 like this.

```
Type            Protocol          Port Range               Source
HTTP              TCP                 80                  0.0.0.0/0
Custom TCP Rule   TCP                8890                 0.0.0.0/0
SSH               TCP                 22                  0.0.0.0/0
```

Am i missing any steps? Please help. Thanks a lot.

Comment: What is the error you are getting in Web Browser Console, while connecting to your Socket?

Comment: it doesnt have error

Comment: Check if the port is really open? [Port Check](http://ping.eu/port-chk/)

Comment: Hi all, it just works magically without any changes. Thanks for the help~

Comment: I might be AWS-SG glitch, I too had similar experiences with other servers.